# Selenium 3 - Firefox Webdriver Error

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

We have our whole Testing project written in Selenium 2 and right now I am looking into making some changes, so it will work with Selenium 3.

My problem is, that even on a low-level basic try, it just don't want to work.

The problem here: the ServiceUrl is automatically set to http://localhost:58439/ and it throws an Error right at the initialization of the driver variable, so I don't even get the chance to navigate to an URL.

Does anyone know where the possible problem might be?

```
Folder Containing Gecko Driver: C:\Programme\IMaT\Output\Release\Bin

Mozilla Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
```

Just installed it right now, so it is the latest version of Selenium 3, latest version of geckodriver and latest version of Mozilla Firefox

Here the Screenshot of the Error Message I am getting:

[image: WebDriverException]

Comment: This can happen if there are version incompatibilities. What are the exact versions of selenium, geckodriver, and firefox? It can also happen if you have a firewall preventing geckodriver from opening a port. What version of Windows are you using? Do you have the same problem if you disable all firewalls?

Comment: It's also helpful if you paste the *text* of your code and errors, instead of screenshots. It makes it a lot easier to read, and to search for answers.

Comment: Thanks - yeah that was the problem ... I accidently copied the 0.10.0 geckodriver rather than the 0.15.0 which caused problems.